# How can I translate a package annotation from java to scala

Tags: java, scala, attributes

I follow the tutorial here

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

to use joda DateTime with jersey. But I am doing it in scala and I am completely at a lost when it come to translate the following snippet of code from java to scala. Can anybody help me or give me link to some tutorial?

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateTime.class, 
        value=DateTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateMidnight.class, 
        value=DateMidnightAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class, 
        value=LocalDateAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalTime.class, 
        value=LocalTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class, 
        value=LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package blog.jodatime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
```

I am supposed to use a package annotation, I have no idea how its done, and Google isn't my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package annotations are not supported in Scala for all I know: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3600. But can't you put these annotations in package-info.java file?

Comment: Oh, I did not knew that. Thank you. I'll probably do as you suggest.